# More Efficient Method For Deleting From Linked List

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am working with a linked list to mimic a list of books and have been asked to create a function to delete a node from the list by using the author's name and book title. I have created a working function and was wondering if there is a cleaner way to go about doing what I did (or more efficient way?).

Here is my code:

```
struct book* delete_from_list(struct book* list){
    if(list == NULL){       //handling an empty list
        printf("There are no books to delete.\n");
        return list;
    }

    //getting book info
    char title[TITLE_LEN], first[NAME_LEN], last[NAME_LEN];
    printf("\nEnter the title of the book: ");
    read_line(title, TITLE_LEN);
    printf("\nEnter the author's first name: ");
    read_line(first, NAME_LEN);
    printf("\nEnter the author's last name: ");
    read_line(last, NAME_LEN);

    struct book* cur = list;
    struct book* prev;
    //conditions for finding book
    bool c1 = strcmp(cur->title, title) == 0;
    bool c2 = strcmp(cur->first, first) == 0;
    bool c3 = strcmp(cur->last, last) == 0;

    for(cur; cur != NULL; prev = cur, cur = cur->next){
        if(c1 && c2 && c3){
            if(cur == list){ //first book in list
                list = cur->next;
                free(cur);
                return list;
            }else{
                prev->next = cur->next;
                free(cur);
                return list;
            }
    }
    printf("Unable to find book, to add a book use the 'a' command.\n");
    return list;
}
```

The above code works and does what I need it to do (at least in the tests I ran), but I'm still very new to working with linked lists and first had to walk through the above code on pencil/paper to make sure I wasn't making any mistakes. So I was wondering if there is a cleaner or more efficient way to delete a node from a linked list?

Additionally, while it is not required in this assignment. I was wondering if there are other conditions I would need to check for when altering a linked list (such as checking for empty list) that I did not check for here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on CodeReview.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the book where book is not the first node? Your code clearly doesn't find the book if it resides somewhere inside the list.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the provided code ***does not*** work correctly.  It will delete a book matching the specified criteria only if that book happens to be the first in the list.  It probably also exhibits undefined behavior if the list is empty (supposing that an empty list is represented by a null pointer).  Additionally, it appears not to maintain nodes' `prev` pointers correctly, therefore corrupting the list when a node is in fact deleted.